# How to update a defaultdict with a value of another defaultdict?

Tags: python

```
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = defaultdict(set)
d2 = defaultdict(set)
d1[1].add('abc')
d1 = {1: {'abc'}}

d2['x'].update(d1) 
d2 = {'x': {1}}`
```

but i suppose it to be:

```
 d2 = {'x': {1: {'abc'}}}
```

The update function should add a pair, but why it only adds the key. How to achieve that effect I want as above? If I use add function, it gets an ' unhashable type' error.

Comment: `{1}` is a `set`, but you expect it to be replaced with a dictionary after the update? (i.e. `{1: {'abc'}}` is a `dict`, vs. `{1}` being a set)

Comment: Yes, with d1 as the value.

Comment: I think I got confused. it seems impossible!

Comment: Your line `d1[1].add('abc')` would cause a runtime error as it stands, what do you think it means? Please post the code that actually runs and has the problem you'd like to solve (i.e. no other problems)

Comment: Not so much "impossible" as "does not make sense" - `dict` and `set` are very different data types, it would appear you got them confused (they do both use `{}` in their literals)

Comment: It works when you use ```d1 = defaultdict(dict)``` and ```d2 = defaultdict(dict)``` or even ```d1 = defaultdict(set)``` and ```d2 = defaultdict(dict)```.

Comment: Let me try. @dmitryro

Comment: And then you assign ```d1[1] = 'abc'```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks!